# LiveData change with callback function

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin, reactive-programming, android-livedata

So I've got this function in the repository:

```
fun getFeaturedLive() : MutableLiveData<Resource<Prod>> {

    val res = MutableLiveData<Resource<Prod>>()
    res.value = Resource.loading(null) //status = loading, data = null, message - null


    client.request({
        it.getOnlineProduct(param1, param2, param3)
    },{//executes on success return from server
        res.value!!.status = Status.SUCCESS
        res.value!!.data = it
    },{//executes on error return from server
        res.value!!.status = Status.ERROR
        res.value!!.message = it.message
        true //error handled
    })

    return res
}
```

The res is returned and after that, when the response from the server comes, the on success function gets executed which modifies the data and the status.

Now in my onViewCreated method, I have something like this:

```
viewmodel.prodLive.observe(this, Observer {
        if (it.status == Status.ERROR) errAlert(it.message)
        if( it.status == Status.SUCCESS) initList(prodList, it.data)
        if (it.status == Status.LOADING) log("loading ...")
    })
```

The server returns that product, the onsuccess function gets called and the livedata gets modified, but the observer doesn't see it. How should I modify the code so that the observer reacts to the data change? I am new to LiveData so if you have any other suggestions, I am glad to hear them.

This is in my viewmodel

```
var prodLive = MutableLiveData<Resource<Prod>>()
        private set
fun init(){
    prodLive = Rep.getFeaturedLive()
}
```

Comment: Does `viewmodel.prodLive` is object of `getFeaturedLive()` ?

Comment: Yes, this is  it 'var prodLive = MutableLiveData<Resource<Prod>>()
            private set'

Comment: You are observing and changing value in different objects

Comment: I am assigning him to the repository function return value. Aren't they supposed to be the same now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LiveData` can't detect if the internals of the value it contains change, only if you give it an entirely new value.

This is what you're currently doing:

```
res.value = Resource.loading(null) // triggers an update, new value set
res.value.status = Status.SUCCESS  // changes existing value, no update
```

And this is what you need to do instead to trigger the `LiveData` observer:

```
res.value = Resource.loading(null) // triggers an update, new value set
res.value = Resource.done(Status.SUCCESS, data) // triggers an update, new value set again
```

I'm of course guessing the syntax here for the last line, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with the implementation of the livedata here. You are not posting the liveData value only setting the data.

Check this link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData#postvalue

- Since your api is asynchronous, you return the livedata value before the result of the api.
- Once the api completes, you are setting the value but not posting the livedata result.
- You have to call livedata.postValue("data") method after setting the data.

Here is how I manage to update UI states. Not familiar with Kotlin so writing in java.

```
private MutableLiveData<Resource<Prod>> mProductsLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public MutableLiveData<Resource<Prod>> getProductsLive() {
        return mProductsLiveData;
        }

    public void callAPI() {

        // Set Resource value to loading before calling api
        mProductsLiveData.postValue(Resource.loading(null)); 

        mRepository.getProductsFromServer(productsRequest)
        .subscribe(this::apiSuccess, this::apiError); 
        }

    public void apiSuccess(Response response) {
        // Set Resource value to Success and set data
        mProductsLiveData.postValue(Resource.success(response.getData()));
        }


    public void apiFailure(Throwable error) {
        // Set Resource value to Error and set Message
        mProductsLiveData.postValue(Resource.error(error.getMessage()));
        }
```